# How do I add and/or modify $jsonSchema for a MongoDB collection from within the NodeJS driver?

Tags: mongodb, schema, node.js

I would like to use the MongoDB native schema functionality in a Node application using the MongoDB NodeJS driver.

I do not want to use Mongoose for this. Mongoose has it's own implementation of Schemas, but has different issues which makes me want to use MongoDB directly.

So far, I have only been able to find how to create a in (official) documentation using the MongoDB via the command line only. I cannot find or figure out how to do this from within a NodeJS app using the NodeJS MongoDB driver.

Also, I cannot find any documentation on how to alter the Schema if one has already been set on a collection.

Anybody know how to do this?

The official docs that I have seen about this topic can be found here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

The answer's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025621/mongodb-add-schema-for-existing-collection

Comment: Hi, welcome to dba.se.  Is there any way you can update your question to include some more specifics, such as what you've already done, what you've tried, and what is giving you trouble?  Right now, the question is a bit [too broad](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and needs some [revision](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/234898/edit) so that people can better help you (as well as anyone else that stumbles across this question in the future who has the same problem).

Comment: Please refer http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/tutorials/crud/

Comment: @mani, I do appreciate your attempt to point me in the right direction, but I am not trying to perform crud operations, but trying to set a $jsonSchema for a collection that already exists or to change the Schema after a while when the requirements change. I can only find how to create a collection that has a schema in the MongoDB Shell, not how to change it or add one if no schema has been set. And then also do all this from inside a NodeJS app:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you are looking for Object Document Mapper. mongoose is a javascript framework which can help you with your requirement https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: @mani. Indeed, Mongoose is able to work with Schemas, but has its own implementation. I would like to work directly with MongoDB for performance reasons and would like to have a more direct way to implement a GridFS solution for user data-storage. Last time I looked into this, Mongoose had issues with this. Hence I would like to find a solution without the use of Mongoose

Comment: @ChrisV As John mentioned , please update all this information in the question so that the people can give a better answer to the question.